# Django RSS feeds: Replace "Read More" with custom string?

Tags: django

I'm generating an RSS feed using the [Django syndication feed framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/syndication/). The items I am linking to, however, aren't articles per se. They are more like events.

Attached is a picture of how a feed item currently looks when parsed:
[image]

My problem here is with the "Read More" link. in my feed class below, the "Read More" anchor leads to URL of the object:

```
def item_link(self, item):
    return reverse('player_page', args=[item.player_set.first().id])
```

How can I make the **anchor text** for this kind of link different? there's no mention of it in the Django docs.

Comment: By `return 'https://other.website.com/path'` This is basically what `reverse(..)` does: it calculates the URL that corresponds with the given view(name) and parameters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean? By return? how does that change the anchor *text*, not URL?

Comment: Ah the text, that was not clear to me.

Comment: I don't think this is part of the content that is rendered in an RSS feed, this is the RSS "viewer" that renders this if I recall correctly. The RSS is only an XML-like stream. A reader can turn this into a "human readable" page, and thus performs some actions on it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem surely there's a way I can at least get rid of this?

Comment: Well take the test: if you use for example Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. Do they render it the same way? Probably not.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's not my question though. It's not a hypothetical question.

Comment: in what way is this a hypothetical comment? If it is not in the RSS stream, then the RSS reader has the freedom to render it any way it wants. I have the impression that the "Read more" is *not* determined by the RSS response, so in that case the server has no means to deterime that.